# TYPO3 multilevel menu with separated main and submenu section

Tags: css, typo3, typoscript

I need to build unusual menu in TypoScript who will have this structure:

```
<div class="main-section">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="submenu">
  <nav>
    <ul id="one">
      <li><a href="#">One sub 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">One sub 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">One sub 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">One sub 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="two">
      <li><a href="#">Two sub 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two sub 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two sub 3</a></li>
    </ul>
     <ul id="three">
      <li><a href="#">Three sub 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three sub 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do that in one Typocript code or should I build two different code for each menu type?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably build two menus, the first prints out the first menu level, the second one the second level. It might be possible to do it in one menu, but that could be hard to do (don't know that for sure). You should of course share common configuration between the two menus.

If you are using two menus, there is also the advantage that you can move the second menu level around independently from the first menu level. That is most probably not be possible when using only one menu.